# Multiple image upload with Codeigniter saving only one file path to MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Now I'm building an application. I have set up a form that will upload multiple image to database. This is my simple code

**View**

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('admin/product/post'); ?>
<table class="table table-stripped">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Code</td>
            <td>
                <?php echo form_input(array('class'=>'form-control','name'=>'kodeproduk')); ?>                                  
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Display</td>
            <td>
                <input class="form-control" type="file" name="userfile[]" id="multiple" multiple="" />    
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Description</td>
            <td>
                <div class="textarea textarea-editor">
                    <textarea name="ket" cols="50" rows="5" class="form-control"></textarea>
                </div>                                  
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-outline btn-block pull-right"><span>Save</span></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<?php echo form_close(); ?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function post(){        
    if($this->_validation()===FALSE){ 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Ooops, there was an error');
        redirect(base_url("admin/product"));
    }else{
        $files = $_FILES;
        $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
            for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++){
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
            $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $fileName = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
            $images[] = $fileName;
        }
        $fileName = implode(',',$images);

        $data = array(  'kodeProduk'                => $this->input->post('kodeproduk'),
                        'ket'                       => $this->input->post('ket'),

                        'GambarBesar'               => $fileName
        );

        unset($data['submit']);                             
        $this->table->add_record($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Product has been saved.');
        redirect(base_url("admin/product"));
    }   
}
```

**Model**

```
public function add_record($data){
    $this->db->insert('produk', $data);
    return;
}
```

And I have a problem when I'm post it, all of the image files upload to the directory on the server, but only ONE of the images actually stores into the MySQL table as a row. So how to fixed my code ? Thanks advance

Comment: It looks like your add_record is after the loop ends and will only run once

Comment: @MattinWashington I've been checked and I tried this [tutorial](http://w3code.in/2015/10/how-to-insert-edit-update-and-delete-data-in-mongodb-with-codeigniter/), but its still only one image stored on database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay a few minor changes might help

```
public function post(){        
    if($this->_validation()===FALSE){ 
        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Ooops, there was an error');
        redirect(base_url("admin/product"));
    }else{
        $files = $_FILES;
        $images = array();
        $cpt = count($_FILES['userfile']['name']);
            for($i=0; $i<$cpt; $i++){
            $_FILES['userfile']['name']= $files['userfile']['name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['type']= $files['userfile']['type'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name']= $files['userfile']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['error']= $files['userfile']['error'][$i];
            $_FILES['userfile']['size']= $files['userfile']['size'][$i];
            $this->upload->initialize($this->set_upload_options());
            $this->upload->do_upload();
            $images[] = $_FILES['userfile']['name'];
        }
        $fileName = implode(',',$images);

        $data = array(  'kodeProduk'                => $this->input->post('kodeproduk'),
                        'ket'                       => $this->input->post('ket'),

                        'GambarBesar'               => $fileName
        );

        unset($data['submit']);                             
        $this->table->add_record($data);
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Product has been saved.');
        redirect(base_url("admin/product"));
    }   
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please try this code i hope this is solve

```
$files = $_FILES;
        $cpt = count($_FILES['fl']['name']);
        if($cpt<=10)
        {
            $number_of_files = sizeof($_FILES['fl']['tmp_name']);
            $files = $_FILES['fl'];
            $errors = array();

            for($i=0;$i<$number_of_files;$i++)
            {
                if($_FILES['fl']['error'][$i] != 0) $errors[$i][] = 'Couldn\'t upload file '.$_FILES['fl']['name'][$i];
            }
                if(sizeof($errors)==0)
                {
                    $this->load->library('upload');
                    $config['upload_path'] = FCPATH . './assets/upload/multiple/';
                    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|jpeg';
                    for ($i = 0; $i < $number_of_files; $i++) {
                        //$_FILES['uploadedimage']['ext'] = $this->get_extension($files['name'][$i]);
                        //echo $_FILES['uploadedimage']['ext'];

                        $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'] = time().$i.$files['name'][$i];
                        $_FILES['uploadedimage']['type'] = $files['type'][$i];
                        $_FILES['uploadedimage']['tmp_name'] = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
                        $_FILES['uploadedimage']['error'] = $files['error'][$i];
                        $_FILES['uploadedimage']['size'] = $files['size'][$i];
                    $fileName[] = $_FILES['uploadedimage']['name'];

                    $this->upload->initialize($config);
                    if ($this->upload->do_upload('uploadedimage'))
                    {
                        $data['uploads'][$i] = $this->upload->data();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        $data['upload_errors'][$i] = $this->upload->display_errors();
                }
            }
        }
    $fname=implode(",",$fileName);
```